# CMake add_custom_command inside of a macro

Tags: macros, cmake, post-build-event

My CMake code looks like the following:

```
macro(macro_name target_name)
    add_custom_command(TARGET ${target_name}
        POST_BUILD
        COMMAND MyCommand)
endmacro()
```

Running this I get the following message:

```
CMake Warning (dev) at ... (add_custom_command):
Policy CMP0040 is not set: The target in the TARGET signature of
add_custom_command() must exist.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0040" for
policy details.  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and
suppress this warning.

The target name "target_name" is unknown in this context.
```

The same code inside of a function works great but I need macro for other things.

CMake policy (http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/policy/CMP0040.html) suggests just ignoring of this warning (and ignoring of adding of postbuild step at all) or treating it as error depending on the settings.

This: http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/macro.html states that parameters behavior in macros is different from one in functions.

**How do I properly refer to macro parameters to get this work?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to figure out the reason: in my case wrong directory was used as ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} inside of the macro. Fixing paths allowed to get desirable result

Comment: Can you copy paste whole solution ? This answer is bit useless.